# Move uploaded file fails after ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, move-semantics, form-data

I know this issue has been tackled a few times but no solution works for me,

I have a javascript function which pulls a file referenced by an  which is as follows

```
function imagePreload(str)
{
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
str = str + "&timestamp=" + timestamp;
var key = [];
var value = [];
var queriesarray = str.split('&');
for(i = 0; i < queriesarray.length; i++)
{
    var pair = queriesarray[i].split('=');
    key[i]= pair[0];
    value[i]= pair[1];
}
for(i = 0; i < queriesarray.length; i++)
{
    if (key[i]=="menu_id") {var menuid = value[i];}
    if (key[i]=="menucategories_id") {var catid = value[i];}
}
for(i = 0; i < queriesarray.length; i++)
{
    if (value[i]=="business") {var fileurlfield = "uploadbizimageid";}
    if (value[i]=="category") {var fileurlfield = "uploadcatimageid" + catid;}
    if (value[i]=="item") {var fileurlfield = "uploaditemimageid" + menuid;}
}

var fileInput = document.getElementById(fileurlfield);

var file = fileInput.files[0];
var imageType = /image.*/;

if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 

} else {
    alert("File not supported!");
}
document.getElementById("maskid").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("imageuploadcontainerid").style.display = "block";

var filetosend = new FormData();
filetosend.append( 'image', file);

$.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=13&format=raw&" + encodeURI(str),
        type: "POST",
        data: filetosend,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(html) {alert("Orwight!");
        document.getElementById('imageuploadcontainerid').innerHTML = html;
        }
});
}
```

As you can see it is designed to make an AJAX call to a php file which is supposed to save that image file to a directory on the same webserver running the above function.

The php in that file looks like this.

```
$rest_id = $_GET['rest_id'];
$menu_id = $_GET['menu_id'];
$menucategories_id = $_GET['menucategories_id'];
$imagetype = $_GET['imagetype']; 

if($imagetype=="business")
{
    $db    = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM g56s_restaurants WHERE rest_id = '$rest_id'");
    $det = $db->loadObject();
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_path = "/images/restaurants/".$rest_id."/";
    $target_path = $target_path ."businesslogo.".$ext.""; 
    echo $target_path;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {    
        echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } else { 
        echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
}
```

Every time I call his script, the upload fails and no error is reported (i.e. no error number). A var dump shows that the the file error variable has a value of 0, and the file size is reported to be in the same order as that of the original file, and it has a tmp name. So in other words the file IS there in the TMP directory.

Directory permissions in the directory being written to are 777. There are no cross domain issues (and I guess no CORS issues) since the script is called from the same website  (the PHP is actually in a JUMI application in a Joomla 3.4 website). However, the script ALWAYS fails to upload the file (the page returns "/images/restaurants/1/businesslogo.jpgNot uploaded because of error #." (since I also echoed the target_path before the error string echoed).

Does anyone know the reason for this and how to get the script to upload correctly ? I am completely stuck on this issue because as far as I can see, everything should work.

Comment: is it possible you are trying to access a folder that is above web root? An open_basedir issue?

Comment: The images directory is under the website root (i.e. its a subdirectory of the website)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue quicker than I thought, it turns out that I also have to specify the document root in the target path, so I amended

```
 $target_path = "/images/restaurants/".$rest_id."/";
```

as

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/restaurants/".$rest_id."/";
```

and it now works :-)